# check if exist record in the another table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

- task; id
- task_assign; id, task_id
- task_state; id, assign_id
- states; id, state_id, define_id

[image]

I want containing at selected IDs in other table

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t.* FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN task_assign AS ta1 ON ta1.task_id=t.id
INNER JOIN task_state AS ts1 ON ts1.assign_id=ta1.id
INNER JOIN states AS s1 ON s1.id=ts1.state_id AND s1.define_id=14
INNER JOIN task_assign AS ta2 ON ta2.task_id=t.id
INNER JOIN task_state AS ts2 ON ts2.assign_id=ta2.id
INNER JOIN states AS s2 ON s2.id=ts2.state_id AND s2.define_id=21
.
.
.
INNER JOIN task_assign AS ta5 ON ta5.task_id=t.id
INNER JOIN task_state AS ts5 ON ts5.assign_id=ta5.id
INNER JOIN states AS s5 ON s5.id=ts5.state_id AND s5.define_id=25
```

this works but when multiplied request it slowing down. Is there another method?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? From what I can tell you want the task id's that exist in ALL tables?? Also, why do this?: `SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t.*` You do know that `t.*` will already include `t.id`??

Comment: Why you joining same table multiple times? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Add sample input data and output what exactly you want to get

Comment: The other tables hasn't task_id. only task_assign has task_id. `SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t.*` this for uniqe records. If I use multiple join, the records repeats. I can use group by.  this is same thing ;)

Comment: There is definitely something wrong here, clarify what you actually need to get, there is almost certainly a better way than inner joining the same table N number of times

Comment: I want records from "tasks" table where containing ids. ex; `where (define_id=14 AND define_id=25)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.id
FROM
    tasks t
INNER JOIN
    task_assign ta1
    ON ta1.task_id = t.id
INNER JOIN
    task_state ts1
    ON ts1.assign_id = ta1.id
INNER JOIN
    states s1
    ON s1.id = ts1.state_id
    AND s1.define_id IN (14,25)
GROUP BY
    t.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT s1.define_id) = 2
```

EDIT - to explain to the OP what this does...
This will first retrieve all records where the define_id is either 14 OR 25, but the `HAVING` clause will only allow the query to return those who have both.

Comment: this is ok but It should has same time other id. `s1.define_id IN (14,25)` this says "or" 14 or 25. I want has 14 and same time has 25.

Comment: There is a problem. If task has two same define_id(ex; 14) and hasn't other define_id(ex 25) It fetch task. It should not fetch that record.